# For a sequence of non-negative integers $d_1, d_2, ..., d_n$, whose sum is even, prove there exists a graph with this sequence as its degree sequence

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

My instinct here was to start breaking things down into cases based on the parity of $n$ and the parity of the elements $d_i$, but that rapidly became not feasible. I'm having a hard time proving this.

It's obvious if $n = 1$. We have a single vertex with $n$ edges.

If $n = 2$, we know that both elements must be odd or both elements must be even (since their sum must be even). This is still trivial.

Once we get to $n = 2$, we start to have a handful of cases, and then things get worse and worse from there... So I suspect this is not a good approach.

Comment: There's a good solution in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_(graph_theory)#Degree_sequence

Comment: You should probably specify that you mean a multigraph and not a graph, because for graphs the condition is much more complicated.

Comment: Imagine 31, 29. The sum is even, we could put 15 and 14 loops, respectively, and tidy up with one edge. This is easily extended to any degree sequence with even sum. One basic condition for simple graphs would require each d_i < n.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, if you allow loops and parallel edges, the problem has a simple solution. If every vertex $i$ has degree $d_i=2k_i$, then adding $k_i$ loops to $i$ yields a solution. This solves the case when all $d_i$ are even. We can reduce the case where some $d_i$ are odd to this previous case as follows. Since $\sum_{i=1}^nd_i$ is even, there are an even number of vertices of odd degree. Pairing up vertices of odd degree, we decrease the degree of all odd vertices by one, i.e. we are back to our original case.